# Paginate con la respuesta de un AJAX - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

A través de unos filtros estoy montando la respuesta de un ajax con el html ya creado.

```
public function filtrarInmueble(Request $request)
    {
        $viviendas = Vivienda::query()
                    ->with('etiqueta')
                    ->with('idistrito')
                    ->with('galeria')
                    ->where('conectado', 1); 

                    //Ejemplo de comprobación

                   if(!empty($request->provincia))
                   {
                    $viviendas->where('provincia', $request->provincia);
                   }
                   //Sigo haciendo comprobaciones....

                   //solo como ejemplo, en caso de obtener el ultimo
                   $last = "";
                   if($last){
                       $viviendas = $viviendas->latest('id');
                   }else{
                   //o devolver la lista
                       $viviendas = $viviendas->paginate(10);
                   }

                   $filtradorHtml = "Aquí va mucho contenido, incluso un foreach iterando todos los productos que corresponden con la búsqueda";

                   //En el caso que no arroje resultados
                   if($filtradorHtml == '') { $filtradorHtml = '<div class="col-12">No hay resultados</div>'; }

                   $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"d-flex col-12\">";
                   $filtradorHtml .= "<div class=\"ml-auto\">";
                   $filtradorHtml .= $viviendas->links(); 
                   $filtradorHtml .= "</div>"; 
                   $filtradorHtml .= "</div>"; 

                   return $filtradorHtml;
```

De por si tengo dos filtros activos simple ya puestos, entonces cuando cargo la página me devuelve 3 página, pero en el momento que paso de página me salen 4 páginas y me anula los filtros.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal??

---

Añado como controlo la paginación.

```
   $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            }else{
                getData(page);
            }
        }
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
            var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#incioPropiedades').position().top}, 'slow');
  
            getData(page);
        });
  
    });
  
    function getData(page){
        $.ajax(
        {
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            url: '?page=' + page,
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "html"
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#resultado").empty().html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert('No response from server');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Probablemente sea porque los botones de los links hacen un request sin enviar los filtros que tú agregas. ¿Revisaste eso?

Comment: Hola @JonatanLavado no comprobe eso, pero la verdad es que no se como hacerlo, voy a buscar